# Copy-pasting image into JavaScript rich-text editor

Tags: javascript, image, richtextbox, gmail, copy-paste

I'm looking for a rich-text editor control that has some way of allowing users to copy-paste images into it, a la Google Mail. I guess I'm hoping there's some way to communicate the binary contents of an image on the clipboard to the browser (and perhaps store these contents in a hidden element somewhere that I can access). If you can't think of a rich-text editor with this functionality included - can anyone think of a way to accomplish this using JavaScript?

This only needs to be functional on IE5+, but any solutions that might work on IE are welcome.

Any help appreciated - let me know in comments if there's any part of this question which isn't clear.

Thanks,

Dom

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What happens in Google mail, is that when you drag an image into a richtext area, it receives a [dragdrop](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Window.ondragdrop) event with the URL of the image. If the image is online, you can have javascript capture this and insert an `<img>` tag. It won't work if the image is on the users file-system though (For security reasons).

Answer (score 0):

This will work in IE if [Chrome Frame](http://code.google.com/chrome/chromeframe/) is installed: http://strd6.com/2011/09/html5-javascript-pasting-image-data-in-chrome/

Comment: Not working in all major browsers like Firefox, Safari. Is there any updates?